# Sidekiq jobs in cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, monit

I run my app on two servers. Each has a job, which checks

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "MailmanCheckJob.perform_later"
end
```

Now this job runs on each server. It checks the new emails and process them. If the email processing takes 4-5 minutes. One message gets picked up by two jobs. 
How do I make sure that each email is picked only once. Each email is marked read once all the processing is over.
it connects to remote redis. They are monitored by monit.
is there an option of running sidekiq in cluster so that only one server picks and runs the job.

-A

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for periodic jobs within Sidekiq

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects#recurring-jobs